# Android Widget Canvas - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, android-canvas, draw

i have a Widget in my app which have a ImageView for displaying a canvas.

If i look into my User Crashs i see that error very frequently (but always just on a few devices):

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver my.package.name.WidgetProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RemoteViews for widget update exceeds maximum bitmap memory usage (used: 5715000, max: 5529600 /*these arent always the same :)*/ ) The total memory cannot exceed that required to fill the device's screen once.
```

my canvas has a dynamic size, it automatically resizes when the user resizes, and has a specified aspect ratio, it is created like that:

```
Resources r = context.getResources();
    SharedPreferences widgets = context.getSharedPreferences("widgets", 0);

            //these are stored in onAppWidgetOptionsChanged when user resizes his widget
    int w = widgets.getInt(widgetId + "_width", 130);
    int h = widgets.getInt(widgetId + "_height", 160);

    w = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, w,
            r.getDisplayMetrics());
    h = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, h,
            r.getDisplayMetrics());

    float scaleX = (float) w / (float) 13;
    float scaleY = (float) h / (float) 16;

    float scale = 1.5f * (scaleX < scaleY ? scaleX : scaleY);//i multiplied it with 1.5 because the canvas was very unsharp

    w = (int) (13 * scale);
    h = (int) (16 * scale);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget);


    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);


 [...]

    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget, bmp);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
```

i guess it is because canvas is 1.5x larger than the widget, but else it is very unsharp.

What can i do?

Thanks in advance.

Metin Kale

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html) specifies that:

> The total Bitmap memory used by the RemoteViews object cannot exceed
>   that required to fill the screen 1.5 times, ie. (screen width x screen
>   height x 4 x 1.5) bytes.

So, use that to control your bitmap size and then use ImageView scaleType fitCenter in your layout to scale-to-fit the bitmap in the widget.